# Signed 2's complement for a hexadecimal number

Tags: ruby

How can I convert a hexadecimal number for instance `'C4D81633'` to signed 2's complement i.e `'-992471501'` using Ruby? I tried

```
['C4D81633'.scan(/[0-9a-f]{2}/i).reverse.join].pack('H*').unpack('l')
```

but the above code is not working well when I give input of length less than 8 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after googling... I add it as a method which is as follows

```
def convert_to_signed_twos_complement(integer_value, num_of_bits)
  length       = num_of_bits
  mid          = 2**(length-1)
  max_unsigned = 2**length
  (integer_value >= mid) ? integer_value - max_unsigned : integer_value
end

hex_to_convert = 'C4D81633'
convert_to_signed_twos_complement(hex_to_convert.hex, 16)

Note: the num_of_bits in method denote the max bit size of the binary you want
```

Comment: I like this method as it work for small strings for ex: 'EC' which should return as -20

Answer (score 7):

The negate operator (`-`) already does a two's compliment:

```
p (-0x1234).to_s(16)    # => "-1234"
```

The trouble is with Ruby's to_s, which notices that it's negated, and outputs it in the way we almost always want--with the minus sign.

If we mask the negated value, though, we'll get Ruby to do what we want:

```
 p (-0x1234 & 0xffff).to_s(16)    # => "edcc"
```

So let's put it all together:

```
def negate(n, num_bits)
  mask = (1 << num_bits) - 1
  -n & mask
end

def negate_string(s, num_bits)
  negate(s.hex, num_bits).to_s(16)
end

p negate_string("C4D81633", 32)    # "3b27e9cd"
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend working with actual numbers when you can. So, take your "stringified hex-ish number", and convert it into an actual integer. (So, as other's have suggested; `'C4D81633'.hex`). I did a few iterations of the method. The first one is @shivashankar's, the other ones are just speed improvements. If you want to black-box it and get performance go with the last one.

```
def signed_twos_complement(integer_value, num_bits)
  length = num_bits
  mid = 2**(length-1)
  max_unsigned = 2**length
  (integer_value >= mid) ? integer_value - max_unsigned : integer_value
end

def signed_twos_complement2(i)
  -(-i & (2**i.to_s(2).length)-1)
end

def signed_twos_complement3(i)
  -(-i & (2**i.bit_length)-1)
end

def signed_twos_complement4(i, bits=i.bit_length)
  -(-i & (2**bits)-1)
end

# Run chunk below in irb or pry to try benchmarking for yourself
require 'benchmark'
n = 9000000
a = Array.new(n) { rand(1...n) };

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { a.each { |z| signed_twos_complement(z, z.to_s(2).length) } }
  x.report { a.each { |z| signed_twos_complement(z, z.bit_length) } }
  x.report { a.each { |z| signed_twos_complement2(z) } }
  x.report { a.each { |z| signed_twos_complement3(z) } }
  x.report { a.each { |z| signed_twos_complement4(z) } }
end
```

Here are my results from my benchmark run

```
    user     system      total        real
6.250000   0.040000   6.290000 (  6.355923)
2.290000   0.010000   2.300000 (  2.347434)
5.840000   0.040000   5.880000 (  5.943748)
2.160000   0.010000   2.170000 (  2.223785)
2.160000   0.020000   2.180000 (  2.218012)
```

Edit: I added `signed_twos_complement4` to be a bit more extensible. You can override intended bits for advanced complementing.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `String#rjust` on your input, first?

```
['C4D81633'.rjust(8,'0').scan(/[0-9a-f]{2}/i).reverse.join].pack('H*').unpack('l')
```

This way, you always have 8 hex digits (except when your input is longer than 8 digits)